# Sinatra: Match arbitrary number of directory occurrences

Tags: ruby, regex, sinatra

I got this route:

```
get %r{/content.json/([\w]+)/([\w]+)/} do
  ...
end
```

and it matches "/content.json/123/abc".
But I would it like to match an arbitrary number of directories, like "/content.json/123/456/abc/def" and hand me the params like this:

```
{"splat":[],"captures":["123","456","abc","def"]}
```

How would the regular expression need to be written?

Answer (score 1):

A possible way to do this could be to match the subdirectories in a single group, and split them in the route itself:

```
get %r{/content.json/([\w\/]*)} do
  dirs = params[:captures][0].split("/");
  ...
end
```

With the request `/content.json/123/456/abc/def`, `dirs` would then contain the array `["123", "456", "abc", "def"]`.

Answer (score 0):

That is impossible. A single regex can have only a fixed number of captures (although some of them may end up capturing `nil`). If you set a limit on the depth, say four, then, you can do like this:

```
%r{/content.json(?:/([\w]+))?(?:/([\w]+))?(?:/([\w]+))?(?:/([\w]+))?}
```